# World to Screen Position after Post-Processing in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, distortion, post-processing

Im looking to find the screen position of a specific world position after distorting the image using the post-processing stack's lens distortion. Before post-processing I would do it like this:

```
Vector3 worldPosVector;
Vector3 screenPosVector = Camera.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPosVector);
```

But it does not factor in the distorting part of the post-processing.

How could I get the screenPosVector after distortion?

Thanks a lot!

[before distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhFNp.png)

[after distortion position of cube is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szumx.png)

Comment: Not sure this is possible/necessary ... post processing as the name says is applied after rendering and calculating everything else and only changes how stuff is rendered, not how `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint` works. What exactly are you doing with it?

Comment: Hi Hugo, somehow I guess I need to track the change of specific vertex positions through the lens distortion post-processing shader. But shaders are not my forte.